# wheres the settings box in lower left corner?

Tags: modeling

when I create a sapling or geometry, I noticed on the tutorials I watch a settings dialog appears where you can change vertex, branches of a tree, etc, how do I get that box?
-thanks.
-Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Press <kbd>F9</kbd>  just after an action that allow some "left bottom box" customization